# Can I perform Maximum likelihood via optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have two $3 \times 3$ matrices $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{f}$.

$\mathbf {f}$ is completely known to me. Also $a_{ij} \in [+1,-1]$

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{f} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
f_{11} \space\space f_{12} \space\space f_{13}\\
f_{21} \space\space f_{22} \space\space f_{23}\\
f_{31} \space\space f_{32} \space\space f_{33} \\
 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} \space\space a_{12} \space\space a_{13}\\
a_{21} \space\space a_{22} \space\space a_{23}\\
a_{31} \space\space a_{32} \space\space a_{33} \\
 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
y &= \sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3} a_{ij}f_{ij} \\
r &= y+n
\end{align}

$n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

I am obersving $r$ and I need to estimate $\mathbf{a}$.

$\underline{Maximum \space Likelihood \space Approach:}$

$\mathbf{A}$: set of all possible $3 \times 3$ matrices $\mathbf{a}$ matrices. size($\mathbf{A}$)= $2^9$.

One way is to generate $\mathbf{A}$, compute $\mathbf{Y}$ (set of all possible outputs) and then compute distance $(r-y)^2$ and pick that corresponds to the minimum distance. This is the $\textit{maximum likelihood}$ way.

$\underline{Example: size(\mathbf{A})=2}$
\begin{align}
y &= a \\
r &= y+n
\end{align}
[image]

Can I pose this problem as an optimization problem that looks for the ML solution in an intelligent way.

I am precisely looking for a solution to this problem. What kind of optimization problem is this. Convex, non-convex ?
Under what conditions, this problem is well-posed and has a solution.

I will be grateful for any useful lead

$\underline{NEW \space EDIT: Previously \space done \space work:}$

- Feldman, J.; Wainwright, M.J.; Karger, D.R., "Using linear programming to Decode Binary linear codes," Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on , vol.51, no.3, pp.954,972, March 2005
- Taghavi, M.H.; Siegel, P.H., "Equalization on Graphs: Linear Programming and Message Passing," Information Theory, 2007. ISIT 2007. IEEE International Symposium on , vol., no., pp.2551,2555, 24-29 June 2007

Comment: Of course it can't be convex. It's discrete. It's probably well-posed, but we can't say because you haven't said what "distance" is, or what we're measuring the distance *to*.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have included necessary definitions in my original post

Comment: But $y$ is a scalar, so the norm is just a squared absolute value?

Comment: Yes $y$ is a scalar. But $y \in \mathbf{Y}$. Each realization of $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbf{A}$ results in a different $y$. So I am after one that is closest to observed $r$ in euclidean sense. You may call it a minimum distance detector

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is still not well posed. Yes, each realization $a$ results in a different $y$. But that just means  *$y$ is a scalar function of $a$.* In no context is $y$ a vector, so the use of a Euclidean norm just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I apologize for being sloppy. its minimizing $(r-y)^2$.